# How to build a c# solution with 64 bit MSBuild?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, 64-bit, gac

I have a batch file that builds a C# solution. It is using MSBuild, specifically the version found at ProgramFiles(x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild. I want to update this to use a 64 bit version of MSBuild. I have tried changing the directory to ProgramFiles(x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\amd64\msbuild but I always get this error while GACing:

"Failed to install assembly into the global assembly cache. Result Code: -2146234299."

I'm not sure what this means. This error seems to only be happening when trying to gac the interops. Any ideas what is causing this?

Comment: What are you GACing?  It isn't clear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure if this will work, but you can try this.

1. Build > Configuration Solution > Active project > Platform- New > Select 64 bit as Platform.